# how to add PKCS12 safebag in .pfx file use bouncycastle?

Tags: bouncycastle, pfx, pkcs#12

When I try to add a crlbag to pfx use x509CRL.it is show me

```
extra in data 1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.4
Sequence
    ObjectIdentifier(1.2.840.113549.1.12.10.1.4)
    Tagged [0]
        DER Sequence
            ObjectIdentifier(1.2.840.113549.1.9.23.1)
            Tagged [0]
                DER Octet String[596] 
    DER Set
```

I am using `PKCS12SafeBagBuilder` mathod to add CRLBag

```
X509CRL crl = CrlBag();
X509CRLHolder acrl = new X509CRLHolder(crl.getEncoded());
PKCS12SafeBagBuilder crlBagBuilder = new PKCS12SafeBagBuilder(acrl);
```

How to add a safebag to PKCS12?